# Why awk script does not work on Mac OS but works on Linux?

Tags: macos, awk, filtering

I have this awk script that I use to filter genes that are differentially expressed. I have a csv file that was created in R.

```
 #Command to get DE genes
awk -F '\t' '$14 < 0.05 && $10 < -1 && $7 > 1 { print > "Genes-Down.csv" }
             $14 < 0.05 && $10 > +1 && $8 > 1 { print > "Genes-Up.csv" }' Results-RPKMs.csv
```

I started doing all my analyses on Mac OS now and the same command does not work. It also does not give any error message. It runs and nothing happens. I also had same problems with other sed commands, but it was easy to make new ones using awk.

---

Update:
   The MacOS X awk is version 20070501. However, the Ubuntu machine has mawk 1.3.3. The command awk --version wouldn't work. Had to use awk -W --version. So I think that is why it works on Ubuntu but was not working in MacOSX. So I downloaded mawk and installed it using fink and now the command works in MacOSX. Thanks for your help.

Update2: Actually the problem was not awk. Usually I create the csv files in R. Then I just run the script to do the filtering. Turns out that if I open the csv files in Excel or save an Excel file in csv format then the script does not work (tried several times with different delimiters). Apparently if you save a spreadsheet as .csv in MacOX (Excel 2011) and try to open it back in Excel it says that it is a SYLK file. There is a description of this on Microsoft website. If I use OpenOffice, it works just fine.

Comment: try grouping the `&&` as `($14 < 0.05 && $10 < -1) && $7 > 1`

Comment: `cat -vet "Results-RPKMs.csv | head -10` . Do you see `^M$` at the end of each line? If so, then `dos2unix Results-RPKMs.csv`. Else edit your question to include results of `awk --verion` from both machines. Good luck.

Comment: I just tried your script with `BSD awk` version 20070501 on MacOS X and it worked without a hitch as did `mawk` and `gawk`

Comment: FYI mawk is a minimally-feature awk, stripped down to help it run a bit faster than some other awks. You'd be much better off installing the feature-rich, POSIX-superset gawk.

Answer (score 39):

I also had the same problem. Installing `gawk` on OSX 10.11.2  through [brew](http://brew.sh/) solved my issue.

```
~$ brew install gawk
~$ gawk --version | head -n 1
GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4-p1, GNU MP 6.1.1)
~$
```

Comment: Worked for me too.

Comment: And then throw `alias awk="gawk"` in your `~/.zprofile` or `~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 29):

A same command name doesn't mean it is the same command. Most basic commands have a different implementation, AWK is an example, but almost all the [GNU core utils](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities) has their equivalent in BSD license. You should be careful with `GNU sed` and `BSD sed`, it's a pitfall too.

In reality Linux generally uses `gawk` or `mawk`:

```
$ man awk
mawk - pattern scanning and text processing language
```

Mac OS uses generally `nawk`:

```
$ man awk
awk - pattern-directed scanning and processing language
```

See [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK_programming_language#Versions_and_implementations) for more informations about AWK implementations.

Answer (score 0):

strong textMaybe you are using `zsh`, in which `awk` and `lsof` for example doesn't work.
Try to use bash script with `#!/bin/bash`, or set bash(`sh`) as shell command as default in this way:

```
# for a List of shell cmd
$ cat /etc/shells

# setbash shell cmd as default
$ chsh -s /bin/bash
```