# How to get modified line numbers in files that have not been committed in GIT yet?

Tags: php, git

Sorry if this sounds easy but I seem to be struggling with some of the more advanced GIT commands.

I am basically trying to find modified line numbers in files that have not been committed yet. Just staged. Im able to get the file names using:

```
git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACMR HEAD
```

Assuming I have an array of file names:

```
$changedFilesList = [0 => 'file1.php', 1 => 'file2.php'];
```

However what I am also interested in getting are the actual line numbers within those files where code was modified. Basically do a diff with the current checked out branch and wherever there are differences, get the line numbers also.

Any tips ?

UPDATE: I have looked at others solutions on stack overflow but they are heavy on bash scripting side. I am looking for a GIT specific or PHP solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git diff with line numbers (Git log with line numbers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455377/git-diff-with-line-numbers-git-log-with-line-numbers)

Comment: I saw that question earlier but that is heavy on bash side. I am looking for a GIT/PHP specific solution if possible. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: The accepted answer is all about git, there’s no Bash in here.

Comment: Yes read the very last sentence of the answer: 'As you can probably tell, unified-diff format doesn't make it easy to figure out line numbers (at least if you're not a machine). If you really want line numbers that you can read, you'll need to use a diffing tool that will display them for you.'

Comment: Right, you need some PHP code to parse the diff and get the line numbers. I retracted my close vote.

Comment: `git blame -s -- <filepath>` output in the format of `<sha> <n>) <content>`. If `sha` is `00000000`, it's a modified but not committed line. `n` is the line number. `content` is what the line is. It's not that heavy for `bash` to parse the output and get the line number. For example `git blame -s -- <filepath> | grep ^00000000 | tr -d ')'`. But if you prefer PHP, you could write a PHP solution to parse the output.

Comment: @ElpieKay but the file is not committed yet..

Comment: @kratos do you mean "not tracked yet"? If it's a new file and not added yet, it's untracked.

Answer (score 0):

Install meld, then after type in your shell `git difftool -d /remote/your_project`. It will open a window which will meet your need.