# What are @@ -20,8 +23,8 @@ random.seed(1001) in git diff?

Tags: git, git-diff

To check differences I run `git diff`:

```
(reg37) C:\Users\banikr\PycharmProjects\Registration\registration>git diff master origin/master
diff --git a/mainfile.py b/mainfile.py
index 94a5113..4b514f1 100644
--- a/mainfile.py
+++ b/mainfile.py
@@ -9,6 +9,9 @@ import matplotlib as mtl
:
```

What do the `@@` signs mean?
Do the numbers indicate the line number of the code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-diff%5D+format

Answer (score 1):

It's a standard GNU format for describe change:
https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Detailed-Unified.html#Detailed-Unified

You can refer to the following response for further information:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24456418/9361998

Comment: Could you summarize the relevant bits here? A link-only answer is fragile.