# How to use awk under fish to split a string by triple dollar signs ($$$) as field separator?

Tags: linux, awk, fish

`awk -F '$'` works well with single-dollar-sign-separated string (`a$b$c` for example), but when it comes to multiple dollar signs, `awk` does not work.

The expected output is: `1$23`, I have tried the following combinations but in vain:

```
$ printf '1$23$$$456' | awk -F '$$$' '{print $1}'
1$23$$$456
$ printf '1$23$$$456' | awk -F '\$\$\$' '{print $1}'
1$23$$$456
$ printf '1$23$$$456' | awk -F '\\$\\$\\$' '{print $1}'
1$23$$$456
$ printf '1$23$$$456' | awk -F '$' '{print $1}'
1
```

I wonder if there is a way to split a string by a sequence of dollar signs using awk?

### update

```
$ awk --version
awk version 20070501
$ echo $SHELL
/usr/local/bin/fish
```

Comment: What awk version are you using? `'\\$\\$\\$'` works for me.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/lgLEiv, `awk -F'\\$\\$\\$' '{print $1}' <<< '1$23$$$456'`  outputs `1$23`

Comment: @BenjaminW. `awk version 20070501` vai `awk --version`

Comment: By the way, I am using fish shell.

Comment: Try `-F'[$][$][$]'`

Comment: Not familiar with fish, but why list bash if that's not what you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is due to [fish quoting rules](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#quotes). The important difference is that fish, unlike Bash, allows escaping a single quote within a single quoted string, like so:

```
$ echo '\''
'
```

and, consequently, a literal backslash has to be escaped as well:

```
$ echo '\\'
\
```

So, to get what in Bash corresponds to `\\`, we have to use `\\\\`:

```
$ printf '1$23$$$456' | awk -F '\\\\$\\\\$\\\\$' '{print $1}'
1$23
```

Answer (score 2):

awk and various shells have nasty behaviours with escaping characters with back-slashes. Various shells could have different behaviours and sometimes you really need to escape like crazy to make it work. The easiest is to use `[$]` for a single symbol. This always works for field separators as `FS` is a regular expression if it is more than one symbol.

```
$ awk -F '[$][$][$]' '{...}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

More \

```
#> printf '1$23$$$456' | awk -F '\\$\\$\\$' '{print $1}'
1$23
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, unfortunately, It does not work with fish shell. I have updated the original post.

Comment: It is not shell but awk version problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24332942/why-awk-script-does-not-work-on-mac-os-but-works-on-linux . I don't have that version to try

Comment: No, it's not an awk problem, I have the same awk version on macOS and it works fine with `'\\$'` in Bash. It's a shell quoting/escaping problem. If you look at the question you link, it actually ends with "the problem was not awk" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not use awk if that's throwing you curves?

```
$: echo '1$23$$$456' | sed 's/$$$.*//'
1$23
```

Why farm it out to a subshell at all for somehting that's just string processing?

```
$: x='1$23$$$456'
$: echo "${x%%\$\$\$*}"
1$23
```

Comment: I changed your tags from bash to linux and fish,  I'm not familiar wish fish, but maybe this will still help.